# Shapefile georeferencing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, georeferencing, greece

I have digitized the internal of a building's floors using ArcMap 10.2.2 and need to georeference the shapefiles now. The only raster file I have, is a google image file which isn't accurate at all. Any suggestions on how can I georeference the shapefiles?

Answer (score 4):

You do not say what country and state your data is in, but I would try to find something with building footprints to georeference against.  For example, OpenStreetMap (available in ArcMap as a Basemap that you can add) has them in some places, and otherwise look for large scale mapping from a local agency which might too.  Otherwise look for high resolution imagery of the area that has already been georeferenced.

Comment: Hey, sorry for not mentioning the country, it's in Greece and I use the Greek Grid projected coordinate system.